# Transaction id from a multisig address

Tags: multi-signature

Suppose Alice sent some coins to a multisig address. Even if that address is assigned to my wallet I will not see the transaction as it doesn't really belong to me. That's fine, Bitcoin-Qt has no way to show "money in your account but locked by multisig" GUI.

Now, I need the txid in order to sign it (via the API) but how do I find that txid when I am a third party (like an escrow for example) and don't have a trace of the transaction via my wallet like Alice would?

I guess I could monitor the blockchain but that sounds foolish, there has to be a better way.

So: given the multisig address xxx give me all transactions registered for that address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Time to answer my own question. I found [biteasy](https://www.biteasy.com), a [blockchain.info](https://blockchain.info/) type tool, which can also query the testnet and has an API.

```
https://api.biteasy.com/testnet/v1/transactions?address=xxx
```

Retruns a list with all transactions linked to that address. I tried it for a multisig one and it shows `BUILDING` which makes sense I guess.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you figured it out yourself so I just want to add that we are going to add multisig support for mainnet as well in a few days and you will be able to use that as well.

BUILDING means that the transaction has been included in a block and it's confidence is "building". There is also a field **confirmations** which you can use as well.

The multisig functionality is pretty new to the site and that's why we haven't documented it yet. It will be done asap.

Comment: Thank you. No idea why I hadn't found your site before but it's a great help! Multisig support would be great.